# print TCHAR[] on console

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm quite sure that it is a stupid issue but it drives me crazy..

how could i print on the console a TCHAR array?

```
DWORD error = WSAGetLastError();
TCHAR errmsg[512];
int ret = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, error, 0, errmsg, 511, NULL);
```

i need to print errmsg...

Comment: Even if you get your program to write UTF16 correctly to the console, Note that the Windows console isn't UTF16 friendly and may just show garbage.  See this question for workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10764920/845092

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on what `TCHAR` is. If you compile with Unicode enabled, `TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t`. Then you can use `std::wcout`, for example:

```
std::wcout << L"Error: " << errmsg << '\n';
```

If Unicode is not enabled, `TCHAR` is an ordinary `char` and you can use the ordinary `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << "Error: " << errmsg << '\n';
```

Comment: What's the point in even using TCHAR if you're going to make your program dependent on whether its a `char` or a `wchar_t`? The whole point of it is to work regardless of what character set you're using, right?

Comment: @Strigoides: It's pretty common to assume `TCHAR` == `wchar_t`.  Pretty much nobody uses `TCHAR`==`char`.  I agree with it being pointless, but I think it _is_ the norm, especially for those still using MFC.

Comment: For this you must use **tprintf**  family, this way it is not dependent on wheather **TCHAR** is **char** or **wchar**

Answer (score 7):

A Google search revealed [this discussion](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/win32programmernetworks/Jan2006/post25461658.asp) which essentially recommends [tprintf](http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/tprintf.9.html).

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <tchar.h> /* _tprintf */

DWORD dwError;
BOOL fOk;
HLOCAL hlocal = NULL; // Buffer that gets the error message string

fOk = FormatMessage(
  FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
  FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS |
  FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
  NULL, dwError, 0, (PTSTR) &hlocal, 0, NULL);
if (! fOk) hlocal = TEXT("Fehler FormatMessage");
_tprintf( TEXT("%d\t%s\n"), dwError, hlocal );
if (fOk) LocalFree(hlocal);
```

Answer (score -3):

I really don't know why but this code worked for me:

```
TCHAR NPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD a = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, NPath);
    string b = "";
    for(int i=0; i<a;i++){
        b+=NPath[i];
    }
    cout << b;
    system("pause");
```

Sorry but i can't really explain why it works and don't have time to search it now. Later!