# UTF-16 on cmd.exe

Tags: windows, unicode, cmd

I've created the directory "•◘▬¨ŤlCęół♥☺☻0" and I would like to make it visible with dir /b command. So far, chcp 10000, chcp 10001 and chcp 65000(utf-8) commands failed(the original name was displayed by "The system cannot write to the specified device", or by empty string, or unicode characters was replaced/ignored. What's the reason and how to fix it? [The official documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490874.aspx) isn't helpful :(

Comment: I don't think its possible. Yet, I might be wrong so please wait for more answers.

Comment: As stated in the answer, this is primarily an issue of selecting a Unicode-capable font. Non-BMP characters probably won't work in any case though.

Comment: Other method:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters/24135341#24135341

Comment: Also

CHCP 65001
DIR > UTF8.TXT
TYPE UTF8.TXT

from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters/24135341#24135341

Comment: Minor note: code page 65000 is UTF-7, while 65001 is UTF-8.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeah,I've just resolved my problem.  It was a fault of default font in cmd.exe which can't manage unicode signs. To fix it(windows 7 x64 pro):

1. Open/run `cmd.exe`
2. Click on the icon at the top-left corner
3. Select properties
4. Then "Font" bar
5. Select "Lucida Console" and OK.
6. Write `Chcp 10000` at the prompt
7. Finally `dir /b`

Enjoy your clean UTF-16 output with hearts, Chinese signs, and much more!

Comment: I'm curious, is the `chcp` really needed? AFAIK it should work even without it since Unicode is independent of codepages.

Comment: Ditto what @Philipp said.  I can see a directory named as you indicated with the default US Windows 437 code page.  Chinese, however, becomes the Unicode replacement character, meaning the font doesn't support it.

Comment: cmd.exe still does not display characters outside of the BMP correctly. (It shows 2 characters instead of 1).

Answer (score 0):

Also from
[Is there a Windows command shell that will display Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters/24135341#24135341)

```
CHCP 65001
DIR > UTF8.TXT
TYPE UTF8.TXT
```

Comment: Note that this answer is for UTF8, not UTF16.

Comment: True, this won't help if you have UTF-16 string, if you try to print it it will break output buffer, no matter the page. Although, its a move in the right direction, see my answer.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I had an answer how to do it in C++ code, not in plain CMD.