# Unicode reading by BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, sockets, unicode, network-programming, bufferedreader

while doing some exercise on socket programming, I encounter a problem in reading Unicode.

I have tested this line outside by creating a new class that is just to input and output Vietnamese ( Unicode characters ) . And It gives the correct output as I input some Unicode characters such as ă, â, ...

```
        inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,StandardCharsets..UTF_8));
```

But when I attached the above line to my socket programming class, It goes wrong and I cannot find out why.

```
        clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
        inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,StandardCharsets..UTF_8));
        String temString = inputLine.readLine();
        os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

The result of temString in the above is a question mark "?" when I typed in "â", which has an int value of 65533.

Please help me fix this problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Windows `cmd.exe` for `System.in`? I'm not sure, but it could be that `cmd.exe` still doesn't use the same character encoding as the rest of Windows. Given your problem description, I find it quite likely that the problem is that whatever writes what you read on System.in is actually not using UTF-8.

Comment: @ChristianHujer System.in is the console in Eclipse I guess?. I'm not sure. But in my case, I code like that in Eclipse and using console in Eclipse to get input. It is correct in the normal class, but it goes wrong in the socket-programming class :(

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764920/utf-16-on-cmd-exe) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500)

Comment: @RichardKennethNiescior The question is that: how can the code above is work in one case but not work in the other.