# How to recover from PrintStream byte encoding?

Tags: java, encoding

**LATEST SSCCEE**

Why does example below output different strings?

```
package tests.java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Try_PrintWriterEncoding3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)b}, Charset.defaultCharset())); 
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); 
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(Arrays.copyOf(b, len), Charset.defaultCharset()));
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); 
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");
    }
}
```

**PREVIOUS EXAMPLES**

I would like to write custom stdout stream, but fails with international encoding.

It is told, that PrintStream converts characters to bytes according to default encoding. This could mean that to decode one should use default encoding too.

But it doesn't work.

Also any other possible encodings don't work.

```
package tests.java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Try_PrintWriterEncoding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final PrintStream oldOut = System.out;

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.write(b); // works
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new char[] {(char)b})); // does not work (garbage type 1)
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)b})); // does not work (garbage type 2)

            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)b}, Charset.defaultCharset())); // does not work (garbage type 2)
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)b}, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); // does not work (garbage type 2)
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");


        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)b}, Charset.forName("CP866"))); // does not work (garbage type 3)
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                oldOut.print(new String(new byte[] {(byte)b}, Charset.forName("Cp1251"))); // does not work (garbage type 4)
            }
        }));

        System.out.println("Привет, мир!");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Where are you running this program? Where is your standard out displayed?

Comment: Standard out is displayed inside Eclipse console, but it doesn't matter, since both outputs go the same way and should give the same results.

Comment: By the time a `byte` reaches the `OutputStream` backing the `PrintStream`, it is already encoded. What are you trying to do overriding `write`?

Comment: Which encoding bytes are in when coming into `write`?

Comment: The default character encoding, or the encoding your provide as an argument to the constructor. See the javadoc, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 }));
```

into

```
 }), true, encoding);
```

Where true means flush on newlines, and encoding as desired, say "Windows-1251".

It will never work for the *real* console, as that is operating system defined.

Otherwise you have to fake a console, as IDEs do. Or ensure that the console (cmd.exe) is [run under Unicode or so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764920/utf-16-on-cmd-exe).

---

```
  System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

        byte[] line = new byte[1024];
        int pos = 0;

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            line[pos++] = (byte) b;
            if (pos >= line.length || b == '\n') {
                flush();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            oldOut.println(new String(line, 0, pos, ENCODING));
            oldOut.flush();
            pos = 0;
        }
    }), true, encoding);
```

First try not giving ENCODING, that defaults to the operating system's.

Comment: I should not touch `PrintStream`, I should recover from it's bytes.

Comment: The question is how to extract correct symbols from bytes, which were appeared in the result of default `PrintStream` working.

Comment: So you capture the bytes in a file? Then you might open that file in a programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit, and switch encodings.

Comment: I think I see UTF-16 (two byte per char); in every case byte-wise conversion in unrealistic. You would need to create a byte array for an input line, and convert that with `new String(bytes, encoding)`.

Comment: I wish to stay in Java only.

Comment: Ensure that you are compiling in the same encoding as the editor uses. That looked to be the case, but try UTF-8. Use `\u041f` instead of `П`. In every case you need a byte array.

Comment: If editor was using different encoding, then plain call would also give garbaged result

Comment: Yes I thought too. It looks like PrintStream does not use a single-byte encoding.