# Why can't I print a unicode character in c with wchar_t?

Tags: c, unicode, wchar-t

Sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int x = sizeof(wchar_t);
    printf("%i\n",x);
    wchar_t t = 0x011E;
    printf("%c\n\n",t);
    wchar_t a = 0x0041;
    printf("%c\n\n",a);
}
```

which will print:

```
4


A
```

0x011E is the UTF-16 [code](http://graphemica.com/%C4%9E) for the character ğ. Why is it not printed?

Comment: I believe you need `%lc` for a `wchar`. You may need to use `wprintf`, too.

Comment: First: the conversion specification `"%c"` expects a value of type `char`, not a value of type `wchar_t`. You are invoking Undefined Behaviour by passing values of the wrong type to `printf()`. Also you need to `#include <stdio.h>` for the correct prototype for `printf()`

Comment: It may depend upon your environment (notably operating system, compiler, etc.) Often, the terminal (e.g. on most Linux) is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @JonSkeet wprintf("%lc\n\n",t); did not solve it for me.

Comment: @pmg I have the include statement I did not show it here.

Comment: @KorayTugay: besides the `"%lc"`, you also need a `setlocale` call, to set the proper locale.

Answer (score 0):

When you print a char you actually just send it's code to console. and console renderer interprets this code with its own character table. so you have to use the same encoding in your source code and in console.

If you are runing windows, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764920/utf-16-on-cmd-exe) how to change encoding in cmd.exe.