# Qt utf-16 output shows question marks in Windows cmd and powershell -- with minimum reproducible example in C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmd, encoding

Previously, I have asked [Qt translations in C++ project are rendered as question marks in cmd and powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74040925/qt-translations-in-c-project-are-rendered-as-question-marks-in-cmd-and-powersh) question. The point of the question was that the help message of `.\app -h`, translated to Cyrillic, is rendered as `?????????`.

Since then, I discovered that in https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qcommandlineparser.cpp, the Qt messages are printed with `qInfo("%ls", qUtf16Printable(message))` on Windows.

In cmd.exe or poweshell.exe I get question marks `?????????`, when trying to output a Cyrillic message this way.

I tried to change the font of cmd.exe and powershell.exe to `Lucida Console` and to execute `chcp 10000` (as proposed here [UTF-16 on cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764920/utf-16-on-cmd-exe)), but this does not help.

Here is the minimum reproducible example:

```cpp
// > cl main.cpp /I C:\Qt\5.12.12\msvc2017_64\include
// > link main.obj /LIBPATH C:\Qt\5.12.12\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Core.lib

#include "QtCore/QtGlobal"
#include "QtCore/QString"

int main()
{
    qInfo("%ls", qUtf16Printable("Привет"));
    return 0;
}

// > main.exe
// ??????
```

I would really appreciate any help. There are two problems here. The first: how can I use `QCommandLineParser` under Windows. The second: if `QCommandLineParser` (using `qInfo("%ls", qUtf16Printable(message))`) is okay and not a bug, then how can I make cmd show it all right.

Comment: What encoding is your cpp file in? Did you tell your compiler that? When you look at the raw bytes output by your program, are they the correct UTF-16 encoding of your input string?

Comment: The encoding of my cpp file in vscode is shown as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally I found the solution. You should create following manifest file for your executable:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <application>
        <windowsSettings>
            <activeCodePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">UTF-8</activeCodePage>
        </windowsSettings>
    </application>
</assembly>
```

Let it will be named as `app.manifest`. In `CMake` project just add `app.manifest` into sources of your executable.

In the `main()` function add two lines of code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    SetConsoleCP( GetACP() );
    SetConsoleOutputCP( GetACP() );
}
```

And voila...

Printing should be done using UTF-8, so:

```cpp
// 1 - works.
QTextStream s( stdout );
s << QString( "Вот оно!!!\n" ) << Qt::flush;

// 2 - works.
fputs( qPrintable( QString( "Опа-на...\n" ) ), stdout );

// 3 - works.
std::cout << u8"std::cout работает!!!\n";

// 4 - DOES NOT work.
std::wcout << L"wcout НЕ работает!!!\n";
```

Comment: If I understand right this will print UTF-8? How is the printing itself should be done?

Comment: This approach will allow you to use Russian in `QCommandLineParser`. You can print with `QTextStream s( stdout ); s << QString( "Вот оно!!!\n" ) << Qt::flush;` or `fputs( qPrintable( QString( "Опа-на...\n" ) ), stdout );`. But `std::wcout` WILL NOT print Russian, so `std::wcout << L"wcout НЕ работает!!!" << std::endl;` will print only English letters.

Comment: So the help message of QCommandLineParser will be printed normally in Russian?

Comment: Sure, you will see normal Russian letters!

Comment: Thank you very much! I upvote. I will try to implement this in my project. May I ask one more question. As this is UTF-8, as far as I understood, I should use Lucida console?

Comment: I tested on my Windows 10, I DID NOT set any font for the `cmd.exe`. I just launched `cmd.exe` and run there test application. I saw normal Russian text. So, I'm not sure about `Lucida console`, I guess, that you should not set any font explicitly.

Comment: I have just tested it for my app. It works!!! Thank you! I accept your answer. Much time has passed, but maybe could you remember where have you found the solution? Just curious.

Comment: Alas, I have just discovered that SetConsoleCP/SetConsoleOutputCP calls breaks the console. My batch files stop working with "is not recognized as an internal or external program"

Comment: Learnt how to circumvent the problem and also simplified your solution. The  problem is that after your code `chcp` in `cmd.exe` gets 65001 instead of 437 and so my batch file breaks down. I use `auto  tmp = GetConsoleOutputCP(); SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 ); std::cout << "абв\n"; SetConsoleOutputCP( tmp );`. And what I meant by simplifying -- this all works without any manifest file at all.

Comment: Hi. You better know what is the problem on your machine. Possibly you did something wrong with the solution. This approach wasn't invented by me, I saw it in the KeePassXC sources. But ok, you wrote that you solved, great, have a nice day. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I don't pretend on the answer, but on Windows for Unicode console output you should do something similar to:

```cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void myMessageOutput( QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const QString & msg )
{
    Q_UNUSED( context );

    std::wcout << msg.toStdWString() << std::endl;

    if( type == QtFatalMsg )
        abort();
}

int main()
{
    _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_U16TEXT );

    qInstallMessageHandler( myMessageOutput );

    const std::wstring rs = L"Привет";
    const auto s = QString::fromStdWString( rs );

    std::wcout << s.toStdWString() << std::endl;

    qDebug() << s;

    qInfo() << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I upvote it. With `_setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_U16TEXT );` I also managed to do it. My question is more about QCommandLineParser though. Because for now it looks like that for Cyrillic letters, one must write their own QCommandLineParser or something.

Comment: I afraid that you will not find any argument parser that can print help and messages with `_setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_U16TEXT );`. Just forgot abot this idea - my $0.02. My own parser can do it, but with `wmain()` function, that is not compatible with `QApplication`,

Comment: Why don't they exist, such parsers (using this _setmode statement)? Interestingly, why Qt doesn't use the statement. Though honestly I don't fully understand what it does and how it works, just found it on this site.

Comment: MSVC asserts on `fputs()`, for example, if `stdout` is unicoded. That is why with Qt you will not reach Russian in Windows console. You can use that approach with `std::wcout` only, so you should be tied to `std::wstring`...

Comment: I can suggest to forget such OS as Windows, they started wrongly with theirs code pages and lost. Linux won, at these times Linux is a candy, cherry on the cake. Lol :)